# How to put text on top of image?

Tags: html, css

I have some HTML and CSS setup for a simple image gallery.
I've been trying to add white text on top of each of the images in the center.

Link to HTML + CSS:
https://jsfiddle.net/babis95/zdhne95u/

```css
.section-images 
{
  padding: 0; 
}
.images-showcase 
{
  list-style: none; 
  width: 100%; 
}
.images-showcase li 
{
  display: block;
  float: left; 
  width: 25%; 
}
.destination-photo 
{
    width: 100%; 
    margin: 0; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    background-color: #000; 
}
.destination-photo img 
{
  opacity: 0.7; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: auto; 
  transform: scale(1.15);
  transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s; 
}
.destination-photo img:hover 
{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.03);
}
.section-images p
{
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<section class='section-images'>
    <ul class='images-showcase'>
      <li>
        <figure class='destination-photo'>
          <img src='https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/blue-suitcase-sun-glasses-hat-600w-1094945555.jpg' alt='Image 1'>
          <p>IMAGE TEXT 1</p>
        </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
        <figure class='destination-photo'>
          <img src='https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/overhead-view-travelers-accessories-essential-600w-425996818.jpg' alt='Image 2'>
        </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
        <figure class='destination-photo'>
          <img src='https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/woman-traveler-suitcase-on-color-600w-578891674.jpg' alt='Image 3'>
        </figure>
      </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

I researched different ways but none seem to work with they way i set up my code:

```
.section-images p
{
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

all this does is, adds a the text in the middle of the whole container, and moves images off of the alignment
This code seem to work on single image in a div, but not when multiple images are used.

Comment: Briefly: lose the `p` tag, use HTML5 `figure -> img` and `caption` tags, and flexbox on the `figure` so you can center the `caption` horizontally and vertically.

Comment: Also briefly: Or set the relevant parent to `position:relative` in order to make `position:absolute` work.  In your case, that is the `figure` element.

Comment: [Did none of these work for you?](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=text+on+image)

Comment: These worked. It was the position:relative that was missing from the code! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need `position: relative;` on your `.destination-photo`

Your Text is placed on an absolute position. Since you don't have a relative position, the images are placed absolutely to the document. Adding `position: relative` to the image would give the p tags a position to start with.